# Deletion of second largest element from a singly linked list

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm currently trying to write a data structure framework for myself. Deletion of the second largest node from a singly linked list works flawlessly in ordinary cases. But fails in a particular one. Here's what I've already tried :

```
//node.h
typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *nextNode;
} Node;

//linkedlist.h
typedef struct LinkedList{
    Node *head;
    int count;
} LinkedList;

//liblinkedlist.c
int deleteSecondLargest(LinkedList *list){
    if(list->count==0)
        return 1;
    if(list->count==1)
        return 2;
    Node *temp = list->head;
    Node *largest = temp;
    Node *prev = NULL;
    Node *prev1 = NULL;
    Node *ptr = temp;

    //finding the second largest node
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(temp->value > largest->value){
            largest = temp;
        }
        else if((temp->value!=largest->value) && (temp->value > ptr->value)){//here's the code failing
            prev1 = prev;
            ptr = temp;
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->nextNode;
    }

    //deleting it
    if(ptr==list->head)
        list->head = list->head->nextNode;
    else
        prev1->nextNode = ptr->nextNode;
    free(ptr);
    list->count--;
    return 0;
}
```

The code fails in the commented block whenever the items in the list are in the order of 1332->34->N. 
I can understand why it is failing because both `temp` and `ptr` is holding 1332 and `else if` is returning false in the second iteration, but I can't find any solution to it. Also, the files in which the functions reside has been commented above the function definition.
Any help?

Comment: Please modify your code in order to have a [mcve].

Comment: Stepping through the code in my head (given the example list you show) then it should work fine as far as I can see. Can you please elaborate on the "fail" part? *How* does it fail? Have you stepped though the code line by line in a debugger (until the end of the function)?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 That is already done in the method if I understood you correctly. I've update the comments. See now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the code fails when the nodes are 1334 and 34. Both temp and ptr are being initialised with 1334. Now in the while loop, at the second iteration, `else if` branch should become true for my code to work. But it is not as both `ptr` is holding `1334` and `temp` is holding `34`. `temp` is not greater than `ptr` and hence the whole branch fails.

Comment: in the step where both temp and ptr equals 1332 shouldn't the if statement fail before it gets to the isValueGreater part? because there both equal then isValueEqual is true -> the if statement fails...

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean. Perhaps you should just switch place of the arguments in the call to `isValueGreater`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz done.

Comment: @DavidWinder I didnot quite get you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that shouldn't work. I have to find the next to largest item in the list. If the item in comparison is already lesser than what I have in hand in `ptr`, it shouldn't be the second largest element for sure.

Comment: What's the "next to largest" in your definition in case the values are not unique?

Comment: @Subhranil the `main` function is still missing.

Comment: ignore my last comment. But shouldn't the value of the ptr be init as 0 (for positive value) and not as the first element?

Comment: Then I suggest you start all over, by using pen and paper to come up with an algorithm. Try a few different alternatives on paper, stepping through the paper algorithms, still on paper. Once you get one that seems to work for a few different test-cases, *then* try and translate the algorithm to code.

Comment: @DavidWinder that'll not work if the list has all negative items.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is what I got using pen and paper, and before implementing, it was looking well and good. After implementation also, it was working fine until I noticed this peculiar case yesterday. You can try it, it works on all other cases.

Comment: @Subhranil please post `main`.

Comment: @Subhrani in that case take INT_MIN. Or simply run first iteration on the list to get max and min values

Comment: @DavidWinder it is solved. Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, you have a problem with the first part of your code: finding the second-largest element in a single-linked list.

In fact, there're three problems in this code:

1. The `ptr` is initialized with first element, which may be too large to be the second maximum.
2. No node is ever demoted from `largest` to `ptr`. That means, for list `34 -> 1332 -> N` your code also does not work.
3. If two maximums have equal values, second one is ignored. That means, for list `123 -> 123 -> N` your code also does not work.

The algorithm of finding two maximums works as follows:

1. Initialization: initialize two current maximums with the lowest possible values or special "uninitialized" flag.
2. In loop over all the elements:

   3. Update both maximums using the current value.

Implementation:

```
// Initialization
Node *largest = nullptr; // for maximum, nullptr means "not initialized"
Node *largest2 = nullptr; // for second maximum, nullptr means "not initialized"
Node *prev_largest = nullptr; // for previous node for maximum
Node *prev_largest2 = nullptr; // for previous node for second maximum

// Iterations
for (Node *cur = list->head, *prev = nullptr; // start of the loop: current node is head, prev is null
    cur != nullptr; // end of the loop: current node is null
    prev = cur, cur = cur->nextNode) { // loop iteration: move both current and prev nodes forward

    if (largest == nullptr || cur->value > largest->value) { // check if we need to update maximum
        // the node which was maximum is now second maximum
        prev_largest2 = prev_largest;
        largest2 = largest;
        // current node is now maximum
        prev_largest = prev;
        largest = cur;
    } else if (largest2 == nullptr || cur->value > largest2->value) { // check if we need to update second maximum
        // current node is now second maximum
        prev_largest2 = prev;
        largest2 = cur;
    }
}
// End of algorithm
// Second maximum is now in variable largest2
// Previous node for second maximum is now in variable prev_largest2
```

Also, please note this algorithm works even if your list contains less than 2 elements (in this case `largest2` will be `nullptr` at the end).

Comment: Yup. That did it. Here's a small tribute : [commit](https://github.com/iamsubhranil/DataStructure_C/commit/e88d52deae0bfa295109e03e005042d381395a5e)

Comment: Btw 1 and 2 were problem. 3 is intentional.

Comment: @Subhranil OK, then please note that in this answer code #3 is fixed: if there're two identical maximums in the list, then `largest2` will point to the righter of them, not to the third one. Anyway, that shouldn't be difficult to fix.

Comment: And if the list contains only one element, there is no point searching for the second largest element. That's why I'm trapping it as an error.

Comment: [Fixed](https://github.com/iamsubhranil/DataStructure_C/commit/74e62cbfc7479cb3b6cc4ac899aacf5e25e76a4f).